# Reference Type Within itself, TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, types, react-navigation

I'm trying to pass types (screen param types) to a field based on the value (screenName) entered.

This is the navigation prop.

```
export interface IEditProfileStackNavigatorProps<RouteName extends keyof EditProfileRoutes> {
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<EditProfileRoutes, RouteName>;
  route: RouteProp<EditProfileRoutes, RouteName>;
}
```

and the routes

```
export type EditProfileRoutes = {
  Options: undefined;
  Name: undefined;
  Username: { token: string };
  Bio: undefined;
  Location: undefined;
  VerifyUser: {
    screenToNavigateTo: keyof Omit<EditProfileRoutes, 'VerifyUser'> | keyof ManageAccountRoutes;
    params: any;
  };
};
```

I would like params to receive param types of a screen based on the screen name inserted in the navigation function.

```
navigation.navigate('VerifyUser', {
  screenToNavigateTo: 'Username',
  params: { some: 'value' } }
)}
```

so that if the screen inserted in `screenToNavigateTo` is `username` the param type will be `{ token: string }` and for the rest it will be `undefined`.

My approach was doing something like

```
export type EditProfileRoutes = {
  Options: undefined;
  Name: undefined;
  Username: { token: string };
  Bio: undefined;
  Location: undefined;
  VerifyUser: {
    screenToNavigateTo: keyof Omit<EditProfileRoutes, 'VerifyUser'> | keyof ManageAccountRoutes;
    params?:EditProfileRoutes['VerifyUser']['screenToNavigateTo'];
  };
};
```

but this seems not to work

Answer (score 2):

You want the two fields of `VerifyUser` to match each other, so what we want is a union of all valid pairings.

This [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-types) [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) takes an object `Routes` and maps it to a new object with the same keys, but the values are objects with the properties `screenToNavigateTo` and `params`.  `screenToNavigateTo` is the key from `Routes` and `params` is the value.

```
type RouteParams<Routes> = {
  [K in keyof Routes]: {
    screenToNavigateTo: K,
    params: Routes[K];
  }
}
```

Then we add `[keyof Routes]` at the end (an [index access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)) to ditch the keys and just get a union of all the elements.

```
type RouteParams<Routes> = {
  [K in keyof Routes]: {
    screenToNavigateTo: K,
    params: Routes[K];
  }
}[keyof Routes]
```

The resolved union that we get from `RouteParams<EditProfileRoutes>` looks like:

```
{
    screenToNavigateTo: "Options";
    params: undefined;
} | {
    screenToNavigateTo: "Name";
    params: undefined;
} | {
    screenToNavigateTo: "Username";
    params: {
        token: string;
    };
} | { ...
```

Using this type, we can now define `EditProfileRoutes` as:

```
export type EditProfileRoutes = {
  Options: undefined;
  Name: undefined;
  Username: { token: string };
  Bio: undefined;
  Location: undefined;
  VerifyUser: RouteParams<Omit<EditProfileRoutes, 'VerifyUser'>> | RouteParams<ManageAccountRoutes>
};
```